# Match the Value and Paste the Result from the Data like (VLOOKUP)

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I have been trying to make an Excel formula as VLOOKUP works but the data i have to match has 3 ID's with `comma ,` in a single cell and Lookup value will have only one ID that matches with one from the 3 ID's.

I have attached a sheet Link any help will be appreciated.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:B27,2,0)
```

Comment: The link does not work.  But If I understand, `=VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",Sheet1!A2:B27,2,0)`

Comment: Thank you but its not working @Scott Craner Below answer is perfect but its very lengthy is there any short way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,(FIND(",",A2,1)-1)),""),'Reference Sheet'!$A$3:$B$28,2,FALSE),"")+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(MID(A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+1,SEARCH(",",A2,SEARCH(",",A2)+1)-SEARCH(",",A2)-1),""),'Reference Sheet'!$A$3:$B$28,2,FALSE),"")+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))),'Reference Sheet'!$A$3:$B$28,2,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working. @Hafiz Is there any short way to do this?